# why '*' faster than hash find, c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, time

I just learnt data structure, can anyone tell me why hash is slow, thank you!

This problem is from LeetCode:
https://leetcode.com/problems/happy-number/

```
bool isHappy(int n) {
    unordered_map<int, int> M;
    M[0] = 0, M[1] = 1, M[2] = 4, M[3] = 9, M[4] = 16, M[5] = 25,\
    M[6] = 36, M[7] = 49, M[8] = 64, M[9] = 81;
    int temp, mark = 0;   //temp is next n, mark is for detect circle 
    while(n){
        temp = 0;
        if(n == 1) return true;
        if(n < 10){
            if(mark == n)
               return false;
            mark = n;
        }
        //calc next n
        while(n){
            temp += (n%10)*(n%10); // 4 ms
            //temp += M[n%10];       // 8 ms
            n /= 10;
        }
        n = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you do to measure that time and what is the value you used for `n`?

Comment: Did you compile with optimizations turned on?

Comment: The hash table needs to calculate the hash and then dereference the table. That has to be slower than simply calculating the value.

Comment: The time is not given by IDE,it  is given by LeetCode, maybe it is not accurate, but use hash is slower , thank you for your answer

Comment: why don't just use a lookup array? It's much faster than hashing

Comment: _Never_ bother with timing results below 5 seconds unless you _know_ fully well that _your timing method is exact_, give or take a few percent.

Answer (score 3):

Why not? Hashing is efficient because of its constant fetch time on average. That's it.

There is no guarantee that it's faster than `*`. Note that your key is usually **NOT** directly used as the key to the hash table(this is called "*direct-address table*" which has its own drawbacks). In general, there is a calculation from your key to the hash key: `hash_key = hash(your_key)`. So the time totally depends on how `hash` is implemented. Once the hash key is calculated, it's just a matter of indexing the table.

As a matter of fact, most common implementation of hashing involves the modulus(%) operation which is most likely slower than '*'. Just think about this: `C = A % B` is equivalent to `C = A – B * (A / B)`.

You might ask what about two `%`(as in the `*` case) vs one `%`(as in the map case)? My guess is `n%10` is optimized to compute only once in the first case.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your question but the use of `std::unordered_map` in this case is an extravagant waste of memory and CPU cycles. A simple array would work just as well here and is almost certainly faster.

```
bool isHappy(int n) {
    static const int M[] = { 0,  1,  4,  9,  16,  25, 36,  49,  64,  81 };
    int temp, mark = 0;   //temp is next n, mark is for detect circle 
    while(n){
        temp = 0;
        if(n == 1) return true;
        if(n < 10){
            if(mark == n)
               return false;
            mark = n;
        }
        //calc next n
        while(n){
            temp += M[n%10];
            n /= 10;
        }
        n = temp;
    }
}
```